# Radio buttons and IF statements

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form of radio buttons, I want some code to run that depends on which radio button is chosen. Originally I did this by making the "name" different for each choice, but it causes problems as the names of each radio button should be the same.

Here's a form code example

```
<li><label for="vsat">YES</label><input type="radio" name="camp" id="vsat" value="vsat" ></li>
<li><label for="vsat2">NO</label><input type="radio" name="camp" id="vsat2"     value="vsat2" ></li>
```

So there's two options, yes or no. I want it to echo "You chose YES" if yes is chosen and "You chose NO" if no is chosen.

Here's how I'm trying to do it

```
if(isset($_POST['vsat'])){
    echo "You chose YES";
}elseif(isset($_POST['vsat2'])){
    echo "You chose NO";
}
```

Make sense? I'm not even sure if it is possible the way I'm trying

Comment: Did you tried to see what is the output of `var_dump($_POST)` or `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: check for the value of `$_POST['camp']`

Comment: Try it! What have you got to lose? You'll learn something in the process.

Comment: @Pred array (size=1)
  'camp' => string 'vsat2' (length=5) when choosing NO

Comment: @RyanMcKenna I know the result. When you understand it, you'll get the answer!

Comment: Also get " Undefined index: vsat2 ", shouldn't that be picked up by POST?

Comment: Nevermind is sorted:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be checking the value of the $_POST['camp'] variable:

```
if ($_POST['camp']) == 'vsat') {
    echo "You chose YES";
} elseif ($_POST['camp'] == 'vsat2') {
    echo "You chose NO";
}
```

The *names* of the variables are passed as $_POST variables when you submit the form, not the IDs.

Comment: Ah I thought it was the names, ID and values, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The value of the selected radio button (`'vsat'` or `'vsat2'`) will be assigned to `$_POST['camp']`, while `'camp'` is the `name` of the radio-buttons:

```
if (isset($_POST['camp']) && $_POST['camp']=='vsat') {
    echo "You chose YES";
} elseif (isset($_POST['camp']) && $_POST['camp']=='vsat2') {
    echo "You chose NO";
}
```

PS: the `isset()` is there to prevent a `NOTICE` popping up if none of the two radio buttons is checked. `$_POST['camp']` will be undefined in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need change your code like this:

```
if ($_POST['camp'] == 'vsat') {
    echo "You chose YES";
}
elseif ($_POST['camp'] == 'vsat2') {
    echo "You chose NO";
}
```

Becouse the value you will check in radio-button-group will be sent to your PHP-script within variable `$_POST['camp']` ('camp' is the name-parameter of radio-button). It will contain value 'vsat' or 'vsat2'.

Comment: I'd upvote if you would explain *why* he needs to change his code to this, as he seems to not know what form submits do or how a form needs to be structured and what gets passed

Comment: @GNi33, Ok. I will do.

Answer (score 1):

this php code

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit_btn'])){
    echo  $_POST['camp'];

    if($_POST['camp']=='vsat'){

    echo "You chose YES";

    }else{
    echo "You chose NO";

    }

}
?>
```

this is form

```
<form method="post" action="">
<li><label for="vsat">YES</label><input type="radio" name="camp" id="vsat" value="vsat" ></li>
<li><label for="vsat2">NO</label><input type="radio" name="camp" id="vsat2"     value="vsat2" ></li>
<li><input type="submit" name="submit_btn" /></li>
</form>
```